# Ubuntu cannot ping rasberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi 2 and a laptop that boots windows10/Ubuntu, the two are directly connected by an ethernet cable. When I try to ping the raspberry pi from windows it works, however when I ping it from Ubuntu nothing gets through. Any help is appreciated, I've already exhausted my limited networking knowledge.

Things I've looked into
-The raspi has an IP address so it is not a DHCP/static error.
-The Ubuntu ethernet port only has an ipv6 address, however the pi only has   an ipv4 address (I figured the systems would be smart enough to handle this but may be wrong).
-I have tried to turn off wifi to force it to go through ethernet, but to no avail.
-I tried to disable the firewall, but that did not work either.

Edit: Perhaps I was too quick in ruling out the DHCP/static problem. It looks like my laptop was on DHCP, I am trying to make it static now

Comment: The obvious approach to fix the problem would be to configure the ethernet port under Ubuntu just like you configured it under Windows.

Comment: is there a single file i can just copy over (maybe interfaces.d)?. The windows side worked without me doing anything, and I'm not sure what configuring the ethernet port entails (ie: mac address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my Ubuntu laptop being setup for DHCP. Both the pi and the laptop need static addresses.

1) System preferences -> network -> wired -> options -> ipv4 settings
2) change "Method" from whatever it was (probably automatic if its the same problem as mine) to manual
3) in "Addresses" click add and create your static ip address/netmask/gateway. I chose my IP based on my raspi's (my raspi was 169.254.17.13).
[image]
4) click save, and make sure wired connections are turned on back in
System preferences -> network -> wired. Then everything should work.